# Is there usually an on-campus interview when hiring a lecturer with a one year contract?

Tags: united-states, job-search, interview

In this case, I am asking about "Lecturer" in the North American sense, which means a faculty member who teaches but is not required to perform research.

Comment: I was hired as a lecturer in the United States by a university on the other side of the United States. I had never visited that university in person, as I lived thousands of miles away. I had a Skype interview instead of an in-person interview with the department. I was hired after the Skype interview. So, in my experience, no, an on-campus interview is not always required.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on circumstances. If the contract is non-renewable then perhaps not provided that the CV and letters of recommendation are strong enough for the hiring department to "take a chance". For a renewable contract, the likelihood of requiring an interview probably increase. Also the kind of institution is a factor.

The institution bears responsibility for the people it puts in front of students so there is pretty strong incentive for interviews. Financial imperatives push the other way.

So, common, yes, but not universal.